# converting xpath to css

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, webdriver

How do you convert the following xpath to css?

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td");
```

Here's what I tried but it didn't work:

1. `By.cssSelector("div[@id='j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700'] > div:nth-of-type(2) > table > tbody > tr > td");`
2. `By.cssSelector("div > #j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700 > div:nth-of-type(2) > table > tbody > tr > td");`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700 tbody td
```

Notice the whitespaces instead of **>** and that allows you to skip child tags

I also do not like that long id. If the ending part of the id is unique you can use partial search

```
[id$='_id700'] tbody>tr>td
```

Comment: Thanks Saifur.  Your 2nd option worked.   If you would, could you please advise in this case as well?   By.xpath("//div[@id='j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")

Comment: Please provide the full html of that table

Comment: Here's as much as allowed.  Thanks!  <div id="j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700"><div class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBgr tertiaryPalette"><h3>Information</h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  first " scope="row"><label>
Bureau &nbsp;</label></th><td class="dataCol  first ">EPIC</td><th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap  first " scope="row"><label>
Program Type &nbsp;</label></th><td class="dataCol  first ">EPIC Live</td></tr><tr><th class="labelCol

Comment: Here's more of the table:  EPIC Live</td></tr><tr><th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row"><label>
Primary Driver &nbsp;</label></th><td class="dataCol ">Speaker</td><th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row"><label>
Location &nbsp;</label></th><td class="dataCol ">Offsite</td></tr><tr><th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row"><label>
Intended Audience &nbsp;</label></th><td class="dataCol ">Physicians</td><th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap " scope="row"><label>
Format &nbsp;</label></th><td class="dataCol ">Breakfast</td></tr><tr><th class="labelCol vfLa

Comment: For EPIC it should be `[id$='_id700'] tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)` and Epic live `[id$='_id700'] tbody>tr>td:nth-child(4)`

Comment: Hi Saifur, I tried what you suggested as well as replacing the $ with * but neither worked.   Thanks anyway - I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3802966 How do you test the `css`?

Comment: By label1 = By.cssSelector("[id$='_id700'] tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)");
By label2 = By.cssSelector("[id$='_id700'] tbody>tr>td:nth-child(4)");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(label1).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(label2).getText());

Answer (score 0):

One should learn how to write css selectors, but a for a quick fix, try: [cssify](http://cssify.appspot.com/)

For example, I put in your xpath and it spit out: `div#j_id0:form:j_id687:j_id693:j_id694:j_id700 > div:nth-of-type(2) > table > tbody > tr > td`